# List and resolve implementations of interface [Windsor Castle]

Tags: .net, mono, castle-windsor, resolve, windsor-3.0

Since Autofac is not working on Mono I'm trying to switch to Windsor IoC framework.
I want to search dll's for implementations of my interface IDataLoader and resolve all of them to instances.

here is my resolving code:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();

System.Reflection.Assembly asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom("/home/konrad/DataLoader.dll");
container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssembly(asm));
IDataLoader loader = container.Resolve<IDataLoader>();
```

Interface looks like this:

```
namespace Viewer.Core.Data
{
    public interface IDataLoader
    {
        PointControl[] GetPositionData(string filePath);
    }
}
```

and implementation:

```
using OpenTK;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Viewer.Core.Data;
using Castle.Windsor;
using Castle.MicroKernel.Registration;

namespace DataLoader
{
    public class StandardDataLoader : IDataLoader
    {
        public StandardDataLoader ()
        {
        }

        public PointControl[] GetPositionData(string filePath)
        {
            return CreateCloud(filePath);
        }

        private PointControl[] CreateCloud(string path)
        {
            //loading data from file code
            return points;
        }
    }
}
```

After resolving I'm getting error:

```
{Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentNotFoundException: No component for supporting the service Viewer.Core.Data.IDataLoader was found   at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Castle.MicroKernel.IKernelInternal.Resolve (System.Type service, IDictionary arguments, IReleasePolicy policy) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Resolve (System.Type service, IDictionary arguments) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.Resolve[IDataLoader] () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer:Resolve ()   at ViewerMultiplatform.DataModel.LoadModel (System.String modelPath) [0x00027] in /home/konrad/hg/ViewerPrototype/OpenTKMultithread/ViewerMultiplatform/Models/DataModel.cs:103 }
```

Is there any additional work I have to do to make my classes resolvable by Windsor framework? I also tried to use register and resolveall methods but nothing works for me.

Comment: I think you need to specify `.WithService.FirstInterface()` or whichever `.WithService` option is relevant - basically you are adding components but you need to register their associated services

Comment: (I think the name `AllTypes` is mentioned to be misleading it's the same as `Classes`)

Comment: Is it in some other assembly? I can't see this after .FromAssembly(asm)

Comment: Added an answer - that seems to work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `AllTypes.FromThisAssembly()` on it's own actually registers anything...

Try `Pick()`

```
container.Register(AllTypes.FromThisAssembly()
            .Pick());
```

I'm still not 100% on the Fluent API yet though :)

This seems to clear it up:

[Castle Windsor Fluent Registration - What does Pick() do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875670/castle-windsor-fluent-registration-what-does-pick-do)

So you can use `Pick()` or `AllTypes().Of<object>()` - specifying `AllTypes()` without picking any types doesn't actually add any types to the container

You also need to specify the services that the components implement:

```
container.Register(AllTypes.FromThisAssembly()
            .Pick().WithService.FirstInterface());
```

or

```
container.Register(AllTypes.FromThisAssembly()
            .Pick().WithService.DefaultInterfaces());
```

Comment: Specifing namespace isn't very convenient but it works thank you Charleh, regards, K.

Comment: Your answer with specifing DefaultInterface was helpful, but now I can't see it after your last edit and I already marked it as accepted

Comment: Ah I'll put that back in, I think both is needed